# Convertir fecha String a Date en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, php7, carbon

Como cambio el formato Fecha entrada `$fecha='31/01/2019';` si es un `string` en formato diferente que acepta la bd MySQL
ejemplo:

entra cadena `fecha $fecha='31/01/2019';`

salida formato `date $fecha ='2019-01-31';`

Answer (score 1):

Con PHP usa `strtotime()` de la siguiente forma

```
//Le pasas el string
 $fecha = strtotime('31/01/2019');
//Le das el formato que necesitas a la fecha
$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$fecha );

echo $newformat;
// 2019-01-31
```

Comment: eso imprimiria 1969-12-31

Comment: la fecha esta devolviendo false o es igual a 0 detecta la validez de la salida con esto $date = ($fecha === false) ? '0000-00-00 00:00:00' : date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);

Answer (score 1):

En caso que no lo sepas, Laravel incluye Carbon, un wrapper de DateTime muy potente, y puedes crear una instancia de fecha fácilmente, utilizando el método createFromFormat:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/01/2019');
```

El resultado es una fecha que se puede almacenar directamente en una base de datos típica.